# How to limit a decrement?

Tags: c++, conditional-statements, procedural-programming

There is a initial game difficulty which is

```
game_difficulty=5   //Initial
```

Every 3 times if you get it right, your difficulty goes up to infinity but every 3 times you get it wrong, your difficulty goes down **but not below 5**. So, in this code for ex:

```
if(user_words==words)   win_count+=1;
else()  incorrect_count+=1;


if(win_count%3==0) /*increase diff*/;
if(incorrect_count%3==0) /*decrease difficulty*/;
```

How should I go about doing this?

Comment: Use an `if` clause to make sure the difficult isn't about to become too low before decrementing it.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen Thats a good suggestion and I thought about it but  my whole program has a lot of conditionals and i am trying to minimize conditionals as much as possible so the logic wont be too much confusing.  Wondering if there are other ways!  Thank You for your answer! :)

Comment: In this case use **while ( n-- > minimum )** , **for** syntax works, but is more messy.

Comment: If you are confident  **game_difficulty > 5 ? -=1 : 5;**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer:

```
if(incorrect_count%3==0) difficulty = max(difficulty-1, 5);
```

But personally I would wrap it up in a small class then you can contain all the logic and expand it as you go along, something such as:

```
class Difficulty
{
public:
    Difficulty() {};

    void AddWin()
    {
        m_IncorrectCount = 0; // reset because we got one right?

        if (++m_WinCount % 3)
        {
            m_WinCount = 0;
            ++m_CurrentDifficulty;
        }
    }

    void AddIncorrect()
    {
        m_WinCount = 0; // reset because we got one wrong?

        if (++m_IncorrectCount >= 3 && m_CurrentDifficulty > 5)
        {
            m_IncorrectCount = 0;
            --m_CurrentDifficulty;
        }
    }

    int GetDifficulty()
    {
        return m_CurrentDifficulty;
    }

private:
    int m_CurrentDifficulty = 5;
    int m_WinCount = 0;
    int m_IncorrectCount = 0;
};
```

Comment: Looks like you beat me to it! :)

Comment: that's… that's just too much ado for nothing. There's really no need for a class.

Answer (score 0):

You could just add this as a condition:

```
if (user words==words) {
    win_count += 1;
    if (win_count %3 == 0) {
        ++diff;
    }
} else {
    incorrect_count += 1;
    if (incorrect_count % 3 == 0 && diff > 5) {
        --diff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
if(win_count%3==0) difficulty++;
if(incorrect_count%3==0 && difficulty > 5) difficulty--;
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be turned into a motivating example for custom data types.

Create a class which wraps the difficulty `int` as a private member variable, and in the public member functions make sure that the so-called *contract* is met. You will end up with a value which is always guaranteed to meet your specifications. Here is an example:

```
class Difficulty
{
public:

    // initial values for a new Difficulty object:
    Difficulty() :
        right_answer_count(0),
        wrong_answer_count(0),
        value(5)
    {}

    // called when a right answer should be taken into account:
    void GotItRight()
    {
        ++right_answer_count;
        if (right_answer_count == 3)
        {
            right_answer_count = 0;
            ++value;
        }
    }

    // called when a wrong answer should be taken into account:
    void GotItWrong()
    {
        ++wrong_answer_count;
        if (wrong_answer_count == 3)
        {
            wrong_answer_count = 0;
            --value;
            if (value < 5)
            {
                value = 5;
            }
        }
    }

    // returns the value itself
    int Value() const
    {
        return value;
    }

private:
    int right_answer_count;
    int wrong_answer_count;
    int value;
};
```

And here is how you would use the class:

```
Difficulty game_difficulty;

// six right answers:
for (int count = 0; count < 6; ++count)
{
    game_difficulty.GotItRight();
}

// check wrapped value:
std::cout << game_difficulty.Value() << "\n";   

// three wrong answers:
for (int count = 0; count < 3; ++count)
{
    game_difficulty.GotItWrong();
}

// check wrapped value:
std::cout << game_difficulty.Value() << "\n";   

// one hundred wrong answers:
for (int count = 0; count < 100; ++count)
{
    game_difficulty.GotItWrong();
}

// check wrapped value:
std::cout << game_difficulty.Value() << "\n";
```

Output:

```
7
6
5
```

Once you have a firm grasp on how such types are created and used, you can start to look into operator overloading so that the type can be used more like a real `int`, i.e. with `+`, `-` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

> How should I go about doing this?

You have marked this question as C++.  IMHO the c++ way is to create a class encapsulating all your issues.

Perhaps something like:

```
class GameDifficulty
{
public:
    GameDifficulty () : 
       game_difficulty (5), win_count(0), incorrect_count(0)
    {}

    ~GameDifficulty () {}

    void update(const T& words)
    {
       if(user words==words)   win_count+=1;
       else              incorrect_count+=1;

       // modify game_difficulty as you desire
       if(win_count%3 == 0)      
          game_difficulty += 1 ; // increase diff no upper limit

       if((incorrect_count%3 == 0) && (game_difficulty > 5)) 
          game_difficulty -= 1; //decrease diff;
    }

   inline int gameDifficulty() { return (game_difficulty); }
   // and any other access per needs of your game

private:
   int game_difficulty;
   int win_count;
   int incorrect_count;
}
```

// note - not compiled or tested

usage would be:

```
// instantiate
GameDiffculty  gameDifficulty;

// ...

// use update()
gameDifficulty.update(word);

// ...

// use access
gameDifficulty.gameDifficulty();
```

Advantage: encapsulation

This code is in one place, not polluting elsewhere in your code.

You can change these policies in this one place, with no impact to the rest of your code.

Comment: Thank You for your answer! I am new to programming and just started with basic stuff so I don't much about the usage of classes.  But the concept definitely is doable .